# How to redirect from a subsite to a page using a script editor?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, redirect

I created a Subsite https://broward.org/BlackHistory but it needs to redirect to this page https://www.broward.org/Pages/BlackHistoryMonth.aspx. I used the following code inside a script editor web part but it doesn't redirect

```
<script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0";url="https://www.broward.org/Pages/BlackHistoryMonth.aspx">
</script>
```

I also used

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0";url="https://www.broward.org/Pages/BlackHistoryMonth.aspx">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add just the meta tag value below in the script editor and try again? Use 30 sec refresh interval first for testing purpose then change it to your desired value.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;URL='https://www.broward.org/Pages/BlackHistoryMonth.aspx'" />
```

[Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html)